# Jupyter Notebook Code Block Not Working With Quotes and Special Characters

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, markdown, jupyter

I am trying to wrap the following code with the markdown code block backticks:

```
users_pipeline = ["$match":{"created.user":{"$exists":True}}},
                  {"$group":{"_id":"$created.user",
                           "count":{"$sum":1}}},
                  {"$sort":{"count":-1}},
                  {"$limit":10}]
                  
results = [doc for doc in db.Houston.aggregate(users_pipeline)]
```

But I think the quotes and special characters (like dollar sign and quotes) are getting in the way. I'm not sure how to work around this. I've tried using escape characters but it doesn't seem to improve

This is what it looks like when I run the cell:
[image: jupyter notebook cell]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing an opening brace, (note the `[{"` before `$match`)

```
users_pipeline = [{"$match":{"created.user":{"$exists":True}}},
                  {"$group":{"_id":"$created.user",
                           "count":{"$sum":1}}},
                  {"$sort":{"count":-1}},
                  {"$limit":10}]
                  
results = [doc for doc in db.Houston.aggregate(users_pipeline)]
```

would make much more sense?

Comment: That was just a typo. Even with an opening brace, it still prints out like the image above. This is for markdown, not a code cell.